# what is the right path that need to be included in a C file for accessing user memory access functions?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am implementing a system call for a guest operating system(Instructional OS) which could be used with below format in a user program:

syscall( syscall number , "string to be printed on console");

this system call should print the second parameter that is a string on console.
Since message can be char[ ] or char * it is treated as address in user space. and to access some address from user space in kernel space, I need to use user space memory access functions like- access_ok() and copy_from_user(). These functions are defined in uaccess.h header file of /usr/src/linux 3.2.0-65/arch/x86/include/asm/ folder.

i include below line in my program to access functions defined in uaccess.h :

```
#include<linux/uaccess.h>
```

But its not working.
On MAKE, its showing an error like

```
syscall.c:39:27: error: linux/uaccess.h: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me ...?

Comment: `#include</usr/src/linux-3.2.0-65/>` That's a directory. You need to include a file, not a directory. Have you ever seen a Linux kernel module source? Google something like `writing my first linux kernel module`.